# maven - create jar for a child and execute goal exec:java for another child by adding first child classes/jar to classpath of second child

Tags: java, maven

I have a `child-1` pom as below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>child-1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <name>child-1</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

and `child-2` pom as below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>child-2</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <artifactId>child-2</artifactId>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>{my main class}</mainClass>
                    <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and `parent` pom as below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>parent</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <modules>
        <module>child-1</module>
        <module>child-2</module>
    </modules>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I need to execute goal `exec:java` on `child-2`, before that the classes in the `child-1` need to be compiled (can be created as jar file but should not install) and should be added to classpath of `child-2` so that, all compiled classes are available for `child-2`. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: A parent does not create a jar nor does it contain code so you can't create a jar from your parent. Only in the child you can create the jar and use it in exec-maven-plugin. Apart from that I strongly recommend to follow the conventions and remove things like `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>`. Put your source code into `src/main/java`. Your unit tests into `src/test/java` etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks, in that case, how can I executed different goals for the two child pom files. For child 1 I need to create jar (should not install) and for child 2 I need to run `exec:java` by adding the generated jar inside target folder of child 1 to classpath of child 2

Comment: Define the execution in each child ? I don't understand why you need to use exec plugin during the build...

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm not doing build, in my case I need to create jar of child 1 (not install) and use that in child 2 to run do `exec:java`, because child 2 is not a build, I have a main class to run in child 2.